# Regatding Riesz functional Calulus Conway

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

This is Chapter VII, $\S$4, second paragraph, from Conway's book: A Course in Functional Analysis:

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $X$ be a Banach space. If $f: G \to X$ is analytic and $x^*\in X^*$, then $z \mapsto<f(z),x^*>$ is analytic on $G$ and its derivative is $<f'(z), x^*>$.

Can anyone tell how the derivative is $<f'(z), x^*>$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, please solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $x^*$ is linear and continuous. Hence:
$$ \frac{\langle f(z+h), x^*\rangle -\langle f(z), x^*\rangle}h = \left< \frac{f(z+h) -f(z)}h, x^*\right> \to \langle f‘(z), x^* \rangle \text{ as } h \to 0 . $$